# width and height for a span does not show up unless a text is entered

Tags: css, html

I have a `<span id="some"></span>` and the css is

```
#some{
      background-color:#000; width:150px; height:50px; 
}
```

The width and height does not show unless something is entered. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`span` is an inline element, so without telling browser that its `display` property as `block` what you do won't work out.

So in brief:

```
#some{
  background-color:#000; 
  width:150px; 
  height:50px; 
  display: block;
}
```

Hope it helps, Sinan

Comment: Could you explain why it appears with a block and why a div takes the style without a block?

Comment: @Jean - `<div>` is `display: block;` by default :)

Answer (score 15):

You can't give a height/width to an inline element, it's sized by it's content, but you can give it `display: inline-block;` like this:

```
#some{
  background-color:#000; width:150px; height:50px; display: inline-block;
}​
```

[See an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/xfgS8/), note that IE7 in particular won't handle this in some situations, so  `display: block;` would work there (but honestly, why not just use a `<div>` then?)...but keep in mind `inline-block` is in the flow, whereas `block` kicks everything down a line.

Comment: @Sinan Why is it a bad habit?

Comment: @Sinan - Because something isn't supported by ancient browsers doesn't make it a bad habit, it just means you need to be aware of your audience.

Comment: @Sinan it's not supported only by Firefox 2.x so it's a good habbit! Even IE6 supports it :)

Comment: @Nick i use it also from time to time but it has more cons than pros. That was just a warning w/o explanation, sorry my bad. But it also behaves differently on even IE7. If you also call it ancient i'm with you :) see: http://drp.ly/1oaf22

Comment: @Sinan - `<span>` is naturally `inline` :)  Also here's the original page if all you've seen is a screen shot: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html quirks mode is a great tool for things like this.

Comment: i took the screenshot myself, to only show the related part of the article:)

Answer (score 1):

One can make span width and height working even without setting display as block by setting position value as absolute to it.

```
.green-box{
      background-color:gold; 
      position:absolute;
      width:300px;
      height:100px;
      border: 2px solid silver;
}
```

Checkout this link for more := https://jsfiddle.net/vipingoyal1000/oa2ssb19/

Answer (score 0):

A common solution is using &nbsp; in the span tag. (I'm assuming you want to make it `display:block;` as well?)

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else mentioned span is inline element, you either need to make it block element (using display:block) or to use block element (div) in its place. In order to better understand inline and block elements, as well the whole html/css rendering model, I suggest you read http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html.

Answer (score 0):

Using display:block; it will work perfectly.

Thanks
Rex

Answer (score 0):

```
border: solid transparent;
```

works on Chrome and Firefox